# Why are certain elements of this python list ignored?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and i'm struggling to understand the output of this simple program:

```
list = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
print(list)
print()
for element in list:
    print(element)
    if 'txt' not in element: list.remove(element)
```

Which gives me this output :

```
['examples_list.txt', 'generate_patterns.py', 'lehoczky_example_3.txt', 'patterns', 'test.py', 'test2.py']

examples_list.txt
generate_patterns.py
patterns
test2.py
```

why are certain elements (such as 'lehoczky_example_3.txt'), ignored by the "for" loop?

Comment: This is one of The Classic Blunders (of Python).  @eumiro's answer is the best solution.

Comment: You can't modify a list while you are iterating over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try list comprehension. This will keep your list of `files` and create a new list `noTxtFiles` without touching the `files`.

```
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
noTxtFiles = [ element for element in files if 'txt' not in element ]
```

And don't use the reserved word `list` for a variable name.

Comment: thanks for the advice! thats actually a pretty elegant way to do it

Answer (score 10):

You cannot remove elements from the list while looping through it. Try and loop over a copy of the list, or create a new one with only the elements you want to keep.

See also [Python strange behavior in for loop or lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742371/python-strange-behavior-in-for-loop-or-lists)

Comment: Technically you _can_ remove elements from a list while looping, you just won't get the result you may have expected.

Comment: @bde - right. In some other programming languages, where you have `for (i = 10; i >= 0; i--)` loops, this reversed iteration is used to remove individual elements safely.

Comment: @eumiro - reverse traversal of a list while removing elements is also valid in Python.  But the real Pythonic solution is to create a new list from the old, as you posted in your answer.

Comment: sure, I meant cannot in the "you cannot cross the beams" sense :-)

Comment: thanks Marco! I feel a little bit silly now that I know what the problem was

Comment: Nothing silly, it's a quite common mistake, coming from other environments. By the way, if you make a habit of treating objects as immutable, functional languages will appear less weird -- where most of the times, the _only_ way to manipulate an object is to build a new one :-)