# check dicts in list and remove invalid dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to check dicts in a list which format is :

- It should have key : `class`,`subject`,`teacher`
- And the value of the key can't not be blank

But I got weird result :
In case 1 `{'subject':'history','teacher':'Marry'}` is invalid
But the code didn't remove it !

And case 2 works well

Here is what I do :

```
# case 1
data_list = [{'class':'A','subject':'math','teacher':'Sam'},
             {'class':'','subject':'','teacher':''},
             {'subject':'history','teacher':'Marry'}]

# case 2
# data_list = [{'teacher': 'Marry', 'subject': 'D'}]


for data in data_list:
    message={}
    message['class'] = data.get('class',required_field) or blank_field
    message['subject'] = data.get('subject',required_field) or blank_field
    message['teacher'] = data.get('teacher',required_field) or blank_field

    if required_field in message.values() or blank_field in message.values():
        print "This dict need to be remove:{}".format(message)
        data_list.remove(data)

print "#### final list ####"  
print data_list     
print "#### final list ####"
```

case 1 result :

```
This dict need to be remove:{'teacher': 'This_field_may_not_be_blank', 'class': 'This_field_may_not_be_blank', 'subject': 'This_field_may_not_be_blank'}  
#### final list ####
[{'teacher': 'Sam', 'class': 'A', 'subject': 'math'}, 
 {'teacher': 'Marry', 'subject': 'history'}]
#### final list ####
```

case 2 result :

```
This dict need to be remove:{'teacher': 'Marry', 'class': 'This_field_is_required', 'subject': 'D'}
#### final list ####
[]
#### final list ####
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJK has pointed out what's going wrong with your code, but you can also make it much shorter, and therefore easier to understand. Bear in mind that the dictionary `get` method will return `None` if the given key isn't in the dict, and that both `None` and the empty string `""` evaluate to false.

So the easiest way to proceed would be to create a new list of the acceptable entries as follows:

```
result = []
for d in data_list:
    if d.get("class") and d.get("subject") and d.get("teacher"):
        result.append(d)
```

You can shorten this by using a comprehension:

```
result = [d for d in data_list
          if d.get("class") and d.get("subject") and d.get("teacher")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you should never delete items from a list which you're iterating over using a `for`.

Here is a similar module : [problem Deleting list items in a for loop (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401601/problem-deleting-list-items-in-a-for-loop-python#5401723)

use th `copy` module. `copied_list = copy.deepcopy(original_list)`