# OpenPyXL - How to delete rows from an Excel file based on some condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to delete the rows from an excel file, knowing the values. I use openpyxl:

`key_values_list` is list with numbers (all are present in the excel file, on column)

```
   wb = load_workbook(src)
    sheet = wb['Sheet 1']

    for i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        if sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value in key_values_list:
            sheet.delete_rows(i, 1)
    wb.save(src)
```

The code above doesn't delete all corresponding rows

Comment: Please add `print(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value in key_values_list)` after the `for` definition to see if it is really `True`.

Comment: Iterating forward will miss rows if two rows to be deleted are next to each other. When you delete row N, row N+1 will become the new row N, but you will next check row N+1, which was N+2 before the deletion.  Simple fix: iterate from the bottom to the top (`range(sheet.max_row, 1, -1)`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll always find a problem with deleting direct elements within a for loop.  Consider this code for a sheet with 12 rows and its respective row value:

```
for i in range(1, sh.max_row + 1):
    print(sh.cell(row=i, column=1).value)

# 1 .. 12
```

Now see what happens when you start deleting stuff:

```
for i in range(1, sh.max_row + 1):
    if sh.cell(row=i, column=1).value in [5,6,7]:
        sh.delete_rows(i, 1)
    print(f'i = {i}\tcell value (i, 1) is {sh.cell(row=i, column=1).value}')

# i = 1     cell value (i, 1) is 1
# i = 2     cell value (i, 1) is 2
# i = 3     cell value (i, 1) is 3
# i = 4     cell value (i, 1) is 4
# i = 5     cell value (i, 1) is 5
# i = 6     cell value (i, 1) is 7
# i = 7     cell value (i, 1) is 9
# i = 8     cell value (i, 1) is 10
# i = 9     cell value (i, 1) is 11
# i = 10    cell value (i, 1) is 12
# i = 11    cell value (i, 1) is None
# i = 12    cell value (i, 1) is None
```

You can see that during the `i in [5, 6, 7]`, the shifting of the rows started at row 6 because row 5 was already deleted, making the original row 6 the new row 5, original row 7 new row 6... etc.  So in the next iteration of `i = 6`, the cell is actually referencing the value of row 7 from the original data.  You effectively skipped iterating through row 6.

The easiest answer is use a `while` loop, not `for`:

```
i = 1
while i <= sh.max_row:
    print(f'i = {i}\tcell value (i, 1) is {sh.cell(row=i, column=1).value}')
    if sh.cell(row=i, column=1).value in [5,6,7]:
        sh.delete_rows(i, 1)
        # Note the absence of incremental.  Because we deleted a row, we want to stay on the same row because new data will show in the next iteration.
    else:
        i += 1
        # Because the check failed, we can safely increment to the next row.

# i = 1 cell value (i, 1) is 1
# i = 2 cell value (i, 1) is 2
# i = 3 cell value (i, 1) is 3
# i = 4 cell value (i, 1) is 4
# i = 5 cell value (i, 1) is 5 # deleted
# i = 5 cell value (i, 1) is 6 # deleted
# i = 5 cell value (i, 1) is 7 # deleted
# i = 5 cell value (i, 1) is 8
# i = 6 cell value (i, 1) is 9
# i = 7 cell value (i, 1) is 10
# i = 8 cell value (i, 1) is 11
# i = 9 cell value (i, 1) is 12

# verify the data has been deleted
for i in range(1, sh.max_row +1):
    print(sh.cell(row=i, column=1).value)

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 8
# 9
# 10
# 11
# 12
```

You can now see that while `i` doesn't reach 12, each row is iterated through because `i=5` has been handled thrice.

If for whatever reason you *must* use a `for` loop to iterate, you might want to consider some [alternative methods such as iterating through a copy or doing it backward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742371/python-strange-behavior-in-for-loop-or-lists)

Comment: hi, do you know how to check if a cell value has NA after calculation then delete/hide the row? I want NA values to not show up in a chart. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to reverse the loop. Since the lines are deleted which mixes up your indexing it makes sense to reverse the order:

```
rows = list(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=sheet.max_row))
for row in reversed(rows):
    if row[0].row == 1:
        break
    if row[5].value != filterBy:
        sheet.delete_rows(row[0].row, 1)
```