# Basic "for" loop question to append elements from one list to another

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to use a `for` loop to empty out all the contents of `animals` into `pets`. There might be a concise code but I want to understand where am I going wrong in the 3 codes below.

**1st Code**

```
animals = ['cat','dog','donkey','mouse','pig']
pets=[]
print(animals)
print(pets)
for value in animals:
    animals.pop()=value
    pets=pets.append(value)
print(animals)
print(pets)
```

**2nd Code**

```
animals = ['cat','dog','donkey','mouse','pig']
pets=[]
print(animals)
print(pets)
for value in animals:
    value=aniamls.pop()
    pets=pets.append(value)
print(animals)
print(pets)
```

**3rd Code**

```
animals = ['cat','dog','donkey','mouse','pig']
pets=[]
print(animals)
print(pets)
for value in animals:
    value=aniamls.pop()
    pets.append(value)
print(animals)
print(pets)
```

Why is the 3rd code at least running, but not the 1st and 2nd codes?

Why are not all the contents of `animals` appended to `pets` in the 3rd code?

Comment: What makes you think that the first two aren’t running?

Comment: `pets = animals.copy()`  should be enough

Comment: `animals.pop()=value` isn't syntactically valid code. You can't have function calls on the right of `=`. And for you third code, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742371/why-does-python-skip-elements-when-i-modify-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) for why elements are skipped.

Comment: Welcome. Did you try to run the third code snippet? There is a typo - trying to access `aniamls` when `animals` is defined instead should not work. Thanks for your time providing code that runs somehow - the third snippet should give a NameError and bail out ...

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your first question. The reason the 3rd code is passing and the first 2 are not, is because

```
pets.append(value)
```

Is the correct way to append to the pets array.

Not all the contents of pets are appended to the animals is because pop removes the last item of the index by default if you don't write an index. If you enter an index as you go through your loop, you will be able to catch the missing ones

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to first question:

In the first piece of code, Python raises a `SyntaxError` because of this line: `animals.pop()=value`. In Python, you assign a variable like this: `x = 3`, where the variable name is on the left of the equals sign and the value you want to assign the variable to is on the right of the equals sign.
`animals.pop()` is a function that returns the last item in the `animals` list, so it cannot be a variable name. You've simply swapped the 2 sides of the equals sign. To make Python not throw an error you should replace that line with `value = animals.pop()`, like you did in the third piece of code.

In the second piece of code, you simply spelled animals wrong (you spelled it like "aniamls", which caused a `NameError`. You also **assigned** the return value of `pets.append(value)` (which is `None`, ie. not returning anything) to `pets` setting the value of `pets` to `None`, which made Python evaluate `pets.append(value)` in the second iteration of the for loop, and since pets is now `None`, Python cannot call the function `append`, a `List` function on it.

### Answer to second question:

The line `for value in animals:` starts iteration through the list `animals`, which basically means that you are running the code in the for loop for every value in animals, and the variable `value` is assigned that value. Because you already have the `value` variable from the for loop, you don't need to create a value variable inside the for loop. Also, `a_list.pop()` returns the last value in `a_list`, so it won't solve your problem anyways. If you would like more information on the `pop()` function for a list, check out @mounika's answer.

### The better way to solve your problem

The concise code you mentioned could be: `pets = animals`. This essentially copies the value of the `animals` variable into `pets`. But, this actually **aliases** `animals` to `pets`, which basically makes changing `pets` also change `animals` in the same way, which you may not want. That's why something like `pets = animals[:]` would be better, which makes a new variable `pets` that has its values separate from the values of `animals`. `animals[:]` basically is a new value which is a list that contains all the items in the list `animals` (essentially a copy of `animals`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask